# Copy only web.config and log4net.config files from a different repository folder other than artifact to azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have two different app service applications in azure which uses same code other than 3 config files. I am currently deploying through release pipeline using Azure app service deploy task (skipping the config files in additional arguments).

The 3 config files are placed in 2 different folders inside another folder azure devops vsts repository.

Is there any other task/powershell script/ftp upload to copy the 3 config and settings files after the deployment task in release pipeline.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what your set-up or requirements are here. Maybe you could post some screenshot(s) of the pipeline and/or directory structure to make it clearer what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Shekar Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 0):

As workaround , you need to checkout the repo where the config file is located to the current source. If you are using yaml pipeline, you can define [checkout step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops) in yaml file, By this, you can fetch and check out other repositories in addition to the one you use to store your YAML pipeline. If you are using classic pipeline, you can do this by [writing a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops#clone-a-second-repo): `git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript.git`. If the repo is not public, you will need to pass authentication to the Git command.

Then the simple way is using [Kudu REST API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) to copy file to azure app service.

Example code:

```
function Upload-FileToWebApp($kuduApiAuthorisationToken, $webAppName, $fileName, $localPath ){

    $kuduApiUrl = "https://$webAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/app/resources/$fileName"
    
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $kuduApiUrl `
                        -Headers @{"Authorization"=$kuduApiAuthorisationToken;"If-Match"="*"} `
                        -Method PUT `
                        -InFile $localPath `
                        -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
}
```

In addition, here is a [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49744813/11508192) you can refer to.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other task/powershell script/ftp upload to copy the 3
> config and settings files after the deployment task in release
> pipeline.

As **Hugh** suggested, you can use PS task to call [Kudu api](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) to upload files to Azure App service. Here's [one similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016882/unable-to-deploy-zip-file-using-kudu-api-to-the-azure-app-service/64059358#64059358) I once answered.

However I think you can also consider another direction:

We can `unzip the .zip which is to be deployed`=>`add those files(web.config, log4net.config) to the extracted folder`=>`archive the folder again=>deploy the newly archived zip file to azure app service`.